# MPMoviePlayerController not resuming while streaming through url

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller, live-streaming

I have MPMoviePlayerController and it start with url but it doesn't resume after pausing, I don't know how to resume after successful buffer of video.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

I tried with this

```
self.moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: url)
                self.moviePlayer?.moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
                self.moviePlayer?.moviePlayer?.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Unknown
                self.moviePlayer?.moviePlayer.play()
                self.presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(self.moviePlayer)
```

Comment: add some code for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` to get notified for state change. Then check `MPMoviePlaybackState` for desired state and resume your video. For more reference you can refer to [apple document for MPMoviePlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/). Also set its `shouldAutoplay` property to `YES`.

Also checkout this answer in case your `self.moviePlayer` is not working properly because it is getting [out of scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29359693/3824808). Try using it as a member variable.

Comment: Thanks, Akshay it's working for getting event on state of MPMoviePlayer,but i think i need to implement buffer implementation for run a video from a url. Do you have any code that work for buffering of video.

Comment: There is no need to add extra code to implement buffering of video it will be handled by this procedure only.

Comment: Ok, Thanks I've added the code to play video in the pause state after every   10 seconds of interval.